# Cohomology of intersection of projective hyperplanes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

I will change my original question a bit for a bounty:

Let $A$ be a reduced finitely generated $\bar{\mathbb{F}}_p$-algebra (integral, if you want).  Let $X$ be a non-empty intersection of hyperplanes in $\mathbb{P}^n_A$, i.e. $X= V_{+}(I) \subseteq \mathbb{P}_A^n$ where $I$ is generated by $f_1,\ldots, f_r$, $r \in \mathbb{N}$ homogeneous polynomials of degree $1$. What can we say about the cohomology of the structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$ of $X$? Can we say more if $r \leq n+1$ or if $r \leq n$?

In particular

> Is it true that $H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_X$) is a quotient of $A$?

My first attempt was to consider the s.e.s. $0 \rightarrow \mathcal{O}(-1) \stackrel{f_1}\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X_1} \rightarrow 0$, look at the l.e.s. in cohomology and proceed inductively. However, this gets quite messy when $I$ is not generated by a regular sequence. People have suggested using the spectral sequences from the Koszul complex for $I \subset A$, but this also gets messy when $I$ is not generated by a regular sequence.

Comment: Form the Koszul complex concentrated in degrees $[-r,0]$ on $\mathbb{P}^n_A$ of the $r$ global sections $f_1,\dots,f_r$ (the complex whose $h^0$ equals the structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$).  Consider the hypercohomology $\mathbb{H}^n(X,-)$ of this complex.  Use one of the two spectral sequences to conclude that the hypercohomology equals $0$ in all degrees other than $0$, where it equals $A$ (using that $\mathcal{O}(-d)$ has all vanishing cohomology for $0<d<n+1$).  Now use the other spectral sequence to relate this to $H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$.